# Identify whether dialog is modal or non modal in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui

How to identify whether the dialog opened is modal or non modal in jQuery?
I am working on an application where I need to take action only on modal dialog and not on non modal dialog.

Comment: Have you tried anything to find out?

Comment: $("#dialog").dialog( "isOpen" ) look docs http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-isOpen

Comment: I compared .ui-dialog division of both modal and non modal but could not find anything that can differentiate between them.

Comment: $("#dialog").dialog( "isOpen" ) will tell whether dialog is open or not. I need to identify whether opened dialog is modal or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [option method](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-option):

```
$("#dialog").dialog("option", "modal")
```

This will return true or false for whether the dialog is a modal or not.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/a3yn0ffx/)**